Django-CMS 4.1.1 Can't edit pages via Page menu or Toggle Structure button
Django 5.0.6
Django-CMS 4.1.1
Stock Install
Following this "Install Django-CMS by Hand" tutorial I am unable to edit any pages I create. All edit options are grayed out under the "Pages" menu and the "Toggle Structure" is disabled. I am attempting these page edits using the superuser account I created during site installation. I even manually added all permissions to my superuser account just in case it was permissions issue. Also when I use the '?edit' option at the end of the page url an error is written to the log file:
Method Not Allowed: /en/admin/djangocms_versioning/pagecontentversion/2/edit-redirect/
I am using the base.html template that was installed by default (I added 'load static'):
    {% extends "bootstrap5/base.html" %}
    {% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
    {% load static %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{% page_attribute "page_title" %}</title>
            {% render_block "css" %}
        </head>
        <body>
            {% cms_toolbar %}
            {% placeholder "content" %}
            {% render_block "js" %}
        </body>
    </html>


I am about to reinstall, any ideas?
I tried to edit pages I created with Django-CMS using several different methodologies:

Page Menu
Toggle Structure
?edit parameter to url

I am using a superuser account and should have all necessary privileges but all editing attempts failed as the options are grayed out.

In django CMS 4.x please use ?toolbar_on instead of the ?edit suffix.

I reinstalled and everything automagically worked. I think it was related to the Nginx <--> Gunicorn <--> static js files pipeline

That sounds reasonable, the statically delivered JS files of the frontend editor ensure that the edit button creates a post request. If they are not loaded, the browser will send a regular get request - which will trigger "method not allowed".
